# Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "rest:campaign-detail"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-extensions

A newbie here in the world of Django. I am struggling with creating a hyperlink for a nested route.

The error I am getting is:

```
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "rest:campaign-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

**Some project setup notes**

- Using django rest framework
- using `DRF-extensions` to create the routes
- Using ModelViewSet
- Expected end points:

  - /accounts/
  - /accounts/< pk >/
  - /accounts/< pk >/campaigns/
  - /accounts/< pk >/campaigns/< pk >/
  - /accounts/< pk >/campaigns/adgroup/
  - /accounts/< pk >/campaigns/adgroup/< pk >/
- Set a namespace of `rest` in urls.py
- Using `HyperlinkedIdentityField` to create the hyperlink. It only works with the parent object i.e.

  - `url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='rest:account-detail')`

However fails with any nested object i.e.

- `url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='rest:campaign-detail')`

The model is quiet simple, an **Account** can have many **Campaigns**, and a campaign can have many **AdGroups**. See code below:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from model_utils import Choices

ORDER_COLUMN_CHOICES = Choices(
    ('0', 'id'),
    ('1', 'keyword'),
    ('2', 'status'),
    ('3', 'match_type'),
)


# Account
class Account(models.Model):
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.account_name


# Campaign
class Campaign(models.Model):
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        Enabled = "Enabled"
        Paused = "Paused"

    account = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='campaigns'
    )
    campaign_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=21, choices=Status.choices, default=Status.Paused)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.campaign_name


# AdGroup
class AdGroup(models.Model):
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        Enabled = "Enabled"
        Paused = "Paused"

    campaign = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='adgroups'
    )
    adgroup_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=21, choices=Status.choices, default=Status.Enabled)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.adgroup_name
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import *
from . import models
from rest_framework_extensions.mixins import NestedViewSetMixin


class AccountViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    queryset = models.Account.objects.all()


class CampaignViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CampaignSerializer
    queryset = models.Campaign.objects.all()


class AdGroupViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AdGroupSerializer
    queryset = models.AdGroup.objects.all()
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models


class CampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="rest:campaign-detail")

    class Meta:
        model = models.Campaign
        fields = '__all__'


class AccountSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='rest:account-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Account
        fields = '__all__'


class AdGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='rest:adgroup-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = models.AdGroup
        fields = '__all__'
```

I have 2 URL files. The project is named **Vanilla** and an app named **rest** where the DRF logic sits.

**Vanilla urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('rest.urls', namespace='rest')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

**Rest urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views
from rest_framework_extensions.routers import ExtendedSimpleRouter

app_name = 'rest'

router = ExtendedSimpleRouter()
(
    router.register(r'accounts',
                    views.AccountViewSet,
                    basename='account')

    .register(r'campaigns',
              views.CampaignViewSet,
              basename='campaign',
              parents_query_lookups=['account__id'])

    .register(r'adgroups',
              views.AdGroupViewSet,
              basename='adgroup',
              parents_query_lookups=['campaign__account', 'campaign'])
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

use hyperlinkedModelSerializer in all of your related serializer. that should work

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately that did not work either.

Comment: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "rest:campaign-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.  can you check the docs and try to fix configured the `lookup_field` ?

Comment: Hi, Could you provide an example please. I have added look-up field to the CampaignViewSet class, but not what what value to assign. Not even sure if I am putting this lookup_field in the right place?